# Consolidating business logic in one place - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a situation, where with time, the same logic has been scattered at different places (stored procedures) in the application. I am trying to bring it in one place and re-use it as required.

**Scenario:**

We sell products online, that are classified into categories and the business rules vary by category. When performing a search, it is possible that multiple products are returned from the same category.

Examples of business rules are:

1. Can the agent sell a product from this category (permission, licensing etc.)?
2. Can the category be sold in a particular state?
3. Is there a tax to be applied on the category?
4. What is the markup for this category?
5. Does this 'product' meet the customer's requirements?

**Current Implementation:**

> Step 1 - Searching

We have a stored procedure that takes @agent_id, @state_id, @markup_amount, @category_id, @customer_id as inputs and returns all products from a specific category, that meet the customer's requirements. The customer's requirements are derived using customer_id. (SELECT 'product' stored procedure)

> Step 2 - Quoting

When adding a particular product to the shopping cart, the above logic is again executed with an additional parameter @product_id, to make sure that the product being added to the shopping cart, satisfies the original requirements (INSERT 'cart' stored procedure)

> Step 3 - Re-Validation

If the customer's requirements change, it is possible that products already in the shopping cart still qualify. The ones that do not qualify have to be removed from the UI (is_active_flag is set 0 on SQL). So we re-use the same logic to determine what the products still meet the customer's requirements. (UPDATE 'cart' stored procedure)

> Step 4 - Sale

The customer can only buy one product from a particular category. When the customer is ready to buy, we re-run the same logic to see if that particular product still passes all business rules including meeting the customer's requirements (INSERT 'sale' stored procedure)

**Consolidation:**

What I am looking to do is consolidate this logic in one place and reference it in different stored procedures, as required. The only variable is @product_id. When the initial search is performed, we do not know what products will qualify. Once we have a finite list of product ids, we are drilling down that list at each step.

For Example: The search stored proc may return 500 products which forms the finite list and the customer may end up adding 3 products to the shopping cart, and in the end can buy only 1. The 3 products that were added and the 1 product that was ultimately sold are a part of the finite list of 500 qualifying products.

What is the most efficient way to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: Just create a new stored proc that allows u to pass whatever variables you need and have that call your other stored procs inside

Comment: What part of this logic are you thinking can be consolidated?

Comment: For a very broad question, I'll submit a very broad suggestion:  Consider a table valued function which consolidate your business logic.  The results can be consumed in a variety of ways.

Comment: @Tab - The 'does this product qualify?' part.

Comment: @John - Precisely what I was thinking and in fact am working on it right now. Not sure if I will hit a snag.

Comment: Make sure you've run a proper business analysis before rushing the database changes. Identify your process stages and corresponding actions - this will give you a hint how to implement the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is create something readable, you can create a boolean sql function that evaluates each product in each scenario.